# Relationship and distinction between VFS and FHS

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel

It is clear that VFS provides programs to access different file systems with same interfaces. Meanwhile, FHS is standard for directory structure.

I would like to have some inputs regarding them because I am not very clear of how they work together.

Answer (score 2):

**VFS** is the virtual filesystem interface, it has been introduced by Sun with SunOS-3 in 1985. It describes the interface between a filesystem implementation and the rest of the kernel. The functions covered by VFS are e.g. open(), read() write() readdir().

**FHS** is a filesystem hierarchy standard and the filesystem hierarchy standard that is used by Linux that was derived from the FHS introduced by Sun for SunOS-4 in 1987.

In other words: VFS allows filesystems to be integrated into the driver structure while FHS just describes how to put files in the system directories.

In other words: there is no relation between both.

Comment: In other words, FHS is a guideline for kernel programmers to follow, right?

Comment: @RonVince No, FHS has nothing to do with the kernel, and little to do with programmers for that matter. FHS is a guideline for distributions (and for programmers if they do their own packaging).

Comment: What is driver structure? Did you actually mean hierarchy structure?